# How do I specify a time given a date object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I am trying to create an object which has both a date field and a time field.  I'd like the time field to be generated based on the date in the date field.  For example:

```
SampleObject.new(
  date = Date.today #Sat, 28 Dec 2013
  time = Date.today.at(5:00pm EST) #Sat, 28 Dec 2013 2013-12-28 17:00:00 -0500 Not valid ruby syntax)
)
```

How can I make `time =` line work as intended?

Comment: I'm assuming that you really mean something other than Object, and that you meant to separate the parameters with commas, because that's not even valid ruby code to instantiate an object.

Comment: Why do you want both a `Date` and a `Time` field? Use [DateTime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) or [Time](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/time/rdoc/index.html) which contains date information.

Comment: Correct DGM, I updated it.

Comment: Also, the Tin Man, I am splitting `Date` and `Time` because the `Time` field will be used in a recurrence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like:

```
DateTime.parse Date.today.to_s + ' 5pm'
#<DateTime: 2013-12-28T17:00:00+00:00 ((2456655j,61200s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: Do *not* edit other people's answers to add your own commentary. It's acceptable to add a comment explaining what you did using the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am interpreting this question as *"a way to set the time of the day on a given date to a given time"*.

One way you could do it is as follows:

```
def set_date_and_time(date = Date.today, time = Time.now)
  this_day  = [date.year, date.month, date.day]
  this_time = [time.hour, time.min, time.sec]

  Time.new(*this_day, *this_time) 
end
```

Hope this helps.